# VPS Ubuntu удаленный рабочий стол

Tags: python, vps, desktop, remote

Можно ли подключиться к удаленному рабочему столу VPS Ubuntu так же, как и к Windows Server?

Answer (score 0):

Смотря что подразумевается под "подключится так же как к windows server." Если речь идёт про RDP, то нет. Для работы на удалённых рабочих станциях на linux используют VNC клиенты. А для управления серверами в частности (vps) используется SSH.

Comment: не совсем так, есть xrdp, который позволяет так же подключаться, как и на виндовс.

Comment: xrdp он немного другой. Я не понял как на нем сделать что-то из rdp 5. Хотяб апп режим

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install gnome-session-flashback xrdp
```

в файле /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh поправить

```
#!/bin/sh
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015, 2017, 2021 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

# Rely on /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman using pam_env to load both
# /etc/environment and /etc/default/locale to initialise the
# locale and the user environment properly.

if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi

export STARTUP=/usr/libexec/gnome-flashback-metacity

test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

и можно подключаться по rdp. Но всё только в базовом виде.